# Return a value from swingbuilder

Tags: groovy, filemaker, swingbuilder

How do I get a value returned as opposed to println which I can not read, in the following script?
I am using Groovy inside Filemaker so need an explicit return 'answer' i.e. the password or a TRUE, and I do not seem to understand how to make the code wait till it finally gets to the point where the correct password is entered.

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
import java.awt.event.ActionListener
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent
import static javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE

count = 2
def answer

SwingBuilder.build{
    frame( id:'root', title:'Enter your PASSWORD', location:[100,100], show:true, pack:true, defaultCloseOperation:DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE){
        //lookAndFeel 'nimbus'
        flowLayout()
        label('Password')
        passwordField(id:'pass', columns:12)
        button('click', actionPerformed:{
        ActionEvent e->
            if (pass.text == 'password'){
            optionPane().showMessageDialog( root, 'OK')

            //RETURN something at this point only when I get here

            dispose()
            } else if (count == 1) {
            optionPane().showMessageDialog(root, 'INCORRECT PASSWORD\nPROCEDURE HALTED', 'PASSWORD', 2)
            dispose()
            } else {
            count--
            message = count ==1 ?'try':'tries'
            optionPane().showMessageDialog(root, "${count} ${message} left", 'NOT VALID', 0)
            }// end if
            pass.text=''
        }// end action
        )// end button
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a boolean field called `successfulLogin` and set it to `true` when the `pass.text.equals("password")`

When do you actually make your frame visible? You might want to just go with JOptionPane.

```
import javax.swing.JComponent
import javax.swing.JPasswordField
import javax.swing.JLabel
import javax.swing.JOptionPane

public boolean loginSuccessful() throws Exception {
    final JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField();
    final JComponent[] components = [new JLabel("Password"), passwordField];
    if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, components, "Enter your PASSWORD", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE) == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        // user clicked ok
        if (new String(passwordField.getPassword()).equals("password")) {
            // password matches
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```